# How can I calculate a trend line in PHP?

Tags: php, math, coordinates, curve-fitting, least-squares

So I've read the two related questions for calculating a trend line for a graph, but I'm still lost.

I have an array of xy coordinates, and I want to come up with another array of xy coordinates (can be fewer coordinates) that represent a logarithmic trend line using PHP.

I'm passing these arrays to javascript to plot graphs on the client side.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Logarithmic Least Squares

Since we can convert a logarithmic function into a line by taking the `log` of the `x` values, we can perform a [linear least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares) curve fitting. In fact, the work has been done for us and a solution is presented at [Math World](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingLogarithmic.html).

In brief, we're given `$X` and `$Y` values that are from a distribution like `y = a + b * log(x)`. The least squares method will give some values `aFit` and `bFit` that minimize the distance from the parametric curve to the data points given.

**Here is an example implementation in PHP:**

First I'll generate some random data with known underlying distribution given by `$a` and `$b`

```
  // True parameter valaues
  $a = 10;
  $b = 5;

  // Range of x values to generate
  $x_min = 1;
  $x_max = 10;
  $nPoints = 50;

  // Generate some random points on y = a * log(x) + b
  $X = array();
  $Y = array();
  for($p = 0; $p < $nPoints; $p++){
    $x = $p / $nPoints * ($x_max - $x_min) + $x_min;
    $y = $a + $b * log($x);

    $X[] = $x + rand(0, 200) / ($nPoints * $x_max);
    $Y[] = $y + rand(0, 200) / ($nPoints * $x_max);

  }
```

Now, here's how to use the equations given to estimate `$a` and `$b`.

```
  // Now convert to log-scale for X
  $logX = array_map('log', $X);

  // Now estimate $a and $b using equations from Math World
  $n = count($X);
  $square = create_function('$x', 'return pow($x,2);');
  $x_squared = array_sum(array_map($square, $logX));
  $xy = array_sum(array_map(create_function('$x,$y', 'return $x*$y;'), $logX, $Y));

  $bFit = ($n * $xy - array_sum($Y) * array_sum($logX)) /
          ($n * $x_squared - pow(array_sum($logX), 2));

  $aFit = (array_sum($Y) - $bFit * array_sum($logX)) / $n;
```

You may then generate points for your Javascript as densely as you like:

```
  $Yfit = array();
  foreach($X as $x) {
    $Yfit[] = $aFit + $bFit * log($x);
  }
```

In this case, the code estimates `bFit = 5.17` and `aFit = 9.7`, which is quite close for only `50` data points.

[image]

For the example data given in the comment below, a logarithmic function does not fit well.

[image]

The least squares solution is  `y = -514.734835478 + 2180.51562281 * log(x)` which is essentially a line in this domain.

Comment: Alright, I'm off to the google races.  I'll get back to you with what I find.

Comment: In theory, your updated comment makes sense.  In practice?  I'm a dunce at math.  I looked at the two equations you mentioned and almost fainted.

Comment: Okay. Well, I did some more research into the problem and have written and tested some code that does this for you, and re-written my answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: That's awesome.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I'm going to break down your code and try to learn what exactly is going on.  I appreciate it.

Comment: I tried to implement your solution, but my y values are coming out way wrong  the range of y values in my array of points is anywhere from 0 to 100.  The trendline I'm coming up with has y values in the negative thousands.  Here's the code:

Comment: Stephen, maybe you can use `pastebin` to share your data? Is it possible it's not really a logarithmic distribution?

Comment: Sure thing.  Here is the array in javascript after I've pulled it from the database view PHP:  http://pastebin.com/JTLQdRhg

Comment: These data look more like an exponential distribution.http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingExponential.html

Comment: I didn't mention it because I didn't think it would matter, but:  The x values are numeric representations of dates.

Comment: Sorry! I had `aFit` and `bFit` confused! I have updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: YES! As soon as I swapped the aFit and bFit everything works perfectly now.  I've been struggling with this for days.  I really appreciate it.  And bonus:  I studied those equations in detail, so I've learned a lot from this hurdle.

Comment: Great. Will you either correct, or remove (probably better) the code you put in your updated question to avoid any confusion a future reader may have?

Comment: You calculate y-squared but don't use it. Does that have any purpose?

Comment: @Blizz - Good point. No; not needed. I was probably just playing around graphing stuff.

Comment: This is a very useful answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using library: http://www.drque.net/Projects/PolynomialRegression/

Available by Composer: https://packagist.org/packages/dr-que/polynomial-regression.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is having problems with the create_function, here is how I edited it.   (Though I wasn't using logs, so I did take those out.)

I also reduced the number of calculations and added an R2.  It seems to work so far.

```
function lsq(){
    $X = array(1,2,3,4,5);
    $Y = array(.3,.2,.7,.9,.8);

    // Now estimate $a and $b using equations from Math World
    $n = count($X);

    $mult_elem = function($x,$y){   //anon function mult array elements 
        $output=$x*$y;              //will be called on each element
        return $output;
    };

    $sumX2 = array_sum(array_map($mult_elem, $X, $X));

    $sumXY = array_sum(array_map($mult_elem, $X, $Y));
    $sumY = array_sum($Y);
    $sumX = array_sum($X);

    $bFit = ($n * $sumXY - $sumY * $sumX) /
    ($n * $sumX2 - pow($sumX, 2));
    $aFit = ($sumY - $bFit * $sumX) / $n;
    echo ' intercept ',$aFit,'    ';
    echo ' slope ',$bFit,'   ' ;    

    //r2
    $sumY2 = array_sum(array_map($mult_elem, $Y, $Y));
    $top=($n*$sumXY-$sumY*$sumX);
    $bottom=($n*$sumX2-$sumX*$sumX)*($n*$sumY2-$sumY*$sumY);
    $r2=pow($top/sqrt($bottom),2);
    echo '  r2  ',$r2;
}
```